# Bash adding numbers from file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to get the sum of all numbers from a file. Each number in the file is on a newline, like so:

```
1
5
2
90
34
```

This is the code I tried:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
$res=0;
$num=`awk -F: '{print $1}' ./nums.txt`
$res=`expr $res $num`
echo $res;
```

But I get this error:

> Error - ./1.sh: line 4: =: command not found
>   Please, help me to solve the issus

Comment: drop the `$` before the variables, except when accessing it when printing the value using `echo`

Comment: expr: syntax error
``
#!/bin/bash
res=0;
num=`awk -F: '{print $1}' ./nums.txt`
res=`expr res num`
echo $res;
``

Comment: Your code is all wrong. You need to loop through the file and add them e.g.  #!/bin/bash    |
res=0    |
while read num; do   |
  res=$((res+$num))  | 
done < ./nums.txt   |
|
echo "$res"   |

I've put | in place of new line characters because the formatting will be messed in this comment.